# Open and edit DWG file without AutoCAD

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I am trying to open a DWG file in VB.NET forms without opening AutoCAD. However, a problem occurs:

> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I also want to edit the image in the DWG file, i.e. most probably a factory layout, and store information about the object used in the layout to figure out the best possible way to reach from source to destination.

This factory layout map is input for a robot which will move according the path available.

Can anybody help? How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you've tried.

Comment: AutoCAD libraries aren't written to support this.  You need to look into a 3rd party library such as RealDWG or Open Design Alliance's Teigha.net

Answer (score 0):

Use [Teigha](http://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/Teigha) or a special program (I don't remember the name) from AutoCad developers to open a dwg file.

Comment: Please do your research before giving an answers to such old questions.